# Dúvida Flutter - Lista

Tags: flutter, dart

Bom dia, pessoal!

Estou com dúvida em trazer os elementos de uma lista. Alguém poderia me auxiliar? Sou novato no `flutter`.

- **O que estou fazendo:**

Tenho uma **lista** que se chama **listaDeObservacoesSelecionadas** que me traz as descrições que foram selecionadas, fiz um foreach para percorrer e adicionar na lista **_serviceList()** a observacoes.descrição.

```
List<String> _servicesList = List<String>();
    
    widget.listaDeObservacoesSelecionadas.forEach((observacoes) {
          _servicesList.add(observacoes.descricao);
        });
```

- **Minha dúvida**:
  Ao adicionar em _servicesList.add as observações ele me traz dessa forma: [cfg, teste]

O que eu preciso que ele me traga apenas a string sem **Colchete** ou seja ficaria: **cfg, teste**

```
print(_servicesList);
[cgf, teste]
```

Comment: Talvez isso possa te ajudar [Descomplicando JSON em flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-comunidade-br/descomplicando-o-json-em-flutter-47e12b87753b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utilizei o método join() para percorrer a List

```
 var list = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    var stringList = list.join("");
    print(stringList); //
```